# Make Sure All Dates Are Within Same Month and Year

Tags: c#

I have a list of dates like this and want to make sure that all dates within that list are within the same month and year. How would I accomplish that?

```
// Should yield true
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates1 = new List<DateTime>() { new DateTime(2022, 11, 30), new DateTime(2022, 11, 14), new DateTime(2022, 11, 2) };

// Should yield false
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates2 = new List<DateTime>() { new DateTime(2022, 11, 30), new DateTime(2022, 11, 14), new DateTime(2022, 10, 2) };
```

Comment: mmm... by comparing theirs months and years?

Comment: Take the first element, if there is no more element then It's fine. For every other element Is it in the same? If not return false.

Comment: I'm not sure what `dates1` and `dates2` are - I interpreted that you wanted to check if all the dates in one list was in the same month and year. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: @OuterSoda yes, making sure all dates within one list are in the same month and year. dates1 yields true, dates2 yields false.

Comment: @Fildor look at the comments above the code. They should yield either true or false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare them with the first:

```
DateTime firstDate = dates1.First();
bool allSameMonthAndYear = dates1
    .All(d => d.Year == firstDate.Year && d.Month == firstDate.Month);
```

Comment: Of course, that's going to throw if the list is empty...

Comment: `var result = dates1.Count()>0 ? dates1.All(d => d.Year == dates1.First().Year && d.Month == dates1.First().Month) : false;`

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes it fails if the list is empty so OP has to handle that case before.

Comment: @ChrisBD: I don't like using `Count()` since it's possible that `dates1` is not a list but for example a database query. Then you will select all records from the table just because you want to know that there is at least one. Either use `dates1.Any()` or ensure that it's a collection before, then you can pre-check if there is at least one. I also don't like using `dates1.First()` twice for each date. Again, if `dates1` is IQueryable you will send a request to a database twice for every date in the sequence. Simply store it in a variable like i did. One-liners are not always better.

Comment: Always good to have an explanation of why and why not. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
var listIsValid = dates1.Any() && dates1.All(e => dates1.First().Month == e.Month && dates1.First().Year == e.Year);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an alternative:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/MJ9weK

```
public static bool Test( IEnumerable<DateTime> testee )
{
    return testee.GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Year, Month = x.Month} ).Count() <= 1;
}
```

But this one is probably less efficient than the others.
It always traverses the whole list and creates a grouping.

On the other hand, this could already give you a hint for how much the items diverge ... if that's of interest.